# Project Euler #10

Tags: python

I'm very new to Algorithms and just started coding weeks back. Please help me out with this one:

The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.

Find the sum of all the primes below two million.

I tried the usual brute method, which ofcourse sucked. I tried reading up about Sieve Algorithms. And implemented this and yes, it runs only for the odd numbers:

```
i=[x for x in range(3,2000001,2)]
print(len(i))
j=0
sum=2
while(max(i)!=j):
    m=0
    while(m<(2000000-(i[j]**2)/(2*i[j]))):
        a=(i[j]**2)+2*m*i[j] 
        if a in i:
            i.remove(a)
        m+=1
    j+=1
for s in range(1,len(i)+1):
    sum+=i[s]
print(sum)
```

The program still takes like more than 5 hours. I stopped it in 3 hours. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Brute force is usually NOT good enough for Project Euler problems. You have to find an algorithm that speeds up finding the correct answer. Look into the field "Analysis of Algorithms" or AofA. Some of the algorithms to some of the problems are highly efficient and give you speed-ups of million fold. You should also look into memoization and dynamic programming (DP).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are trying to learn, so I will not give you the full solution, just the path.

- Don't mess with lists, putting elements in and out, checking if they are in, etc. That is a recipe for inefficiency. Instead, keep a list of known primes.
- Write comments. I have been staring at your code for some minutes and I have no clue what it does.
- Use `math` functions when appropiate. `math.sqrt` is faster than `**0.5` (about 30% more).
- This block:

  `for s in range(1,len(i)+1):
      sum+=i[s]`

  hurts. You can get the sum of a list by just: typing `sum(i)`
- `[x for x in range(3,2000001,2)]` is exactly the same as `range(3,2000001,2)` (in Python2) or `list(range(3,2000001,2))` (in Python3).
- Don't use variable names as `i`,`a`, `m`. It is not clear what they are.

How do you know if a number is prime? For all the primes below it, check if they divide your number. If none does, save it. In fact, you can check only those primes that are smaller than the square root of your number.

If you want to trade memory for speed, you can just use @vamosrafa 's function, and do `sum(prime(2e6))`. (In Python2 change `range` for `xrange`). You will only need memory to hold a couple of numbers at the same time, but will be doing a lot of unnecessary divisions (if it is not divisible by 3 nor 5, it will not be divisible by 15).

Comment: Those were some really handy tips! Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Davidmh: Yeah, the yield approach will consume memory, that's why, it is not a good method, by I was struggling with the sieve method, it was taking 5 hours of time.

Answer (score 3):

The sieve is a good approach, but your implementation is confusing and evidently not working correctly. Consider this very simple (unoptimised) implementation:

```
def prime_sieve(max_):
    """Create a list containing all prime numbers equal to or less than max_."""
    primes = list(range(max_+1)) # all numbers 0 to max_
    primes[1] = 0 # 1 is not prime
    for number in primes: # iterate through all numbers
        if number: # if not 0 (i.e. prime)
            for multiple in range(2, (max_ // number) + 1):
                primes[number * multiple] = 0 # set multiples to zero
    return primes
```

It could be made more efficient, but runs on my machine in around two seconds for `max_ == 2000000`.

Using `for` loops is generally a better bet than `while` loops for iterating over containers like lists. Note also that I leave the non-primes in place in the list, but set them to zero - otherwise the indexing (`i[j]` in your code) will break.

For the test example:

```
>>> prime_sieve(10)
[0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0]
>>> list(filter(None, prime_sieve(10)))
[2, 3, 5, 7]
>>> sum(prime_sieve(10))
17
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck up in the same, and spent two night outs, to solve this.

Then, I picked up mark pilgrim's `DIVE INTO PYTHON`, and there is a chapter about generator function, I applied that technique to solve this. Here's the generator function which will solve this problem:

```
def prime(max):

    for n in range(2,max):

        for x in range(2,int(n**0.5) + 1):

            if n%x == 0:


                break
        else:

            yield n
```

Now, write another function sum which will call this, either at shell or in this program itself, I had called the sum at the shell, but this will solve your problem.

Good Luck! :)

Comment: Although a good approach for testing primes generally, this does not address the user's question (what is wrong with their implementation) nor does it use the sieve approach referred to.

Comment: Yes, I have posted an optimized approach ,with sieve approach,for me, it took same amount of time for processing, 5 hours.

Comment: Wow, really?! What are you running it on? The relatively naive sieve in my example took about 2 seconds. You might want to take your code over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com and get some help speeding it up.

Answer (score 0):

One improvement can be made based on the code provided by @jonrsharpe - replace `for multiple in range(2, (max_//number)+1):` with `for multiple in range(number, (max_//number)+1):`

```
def prime_sieve2(max_):
        primes = list(range(max_+1))
        primes[1] = 0 
        for number in primes:
                if number:
                        # starting from number rather than 2 
                        for multiple in range(number, (max_//number)+1): 
                                primes[number * multiple] = 0 
        return primes
```

The evaluation steps before (you can see the evaluation **from 2 to number^2** can be skipped):

```
check 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14,...
check 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21,...  (6 is already checked by '2')
check 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35,...  (10, 15, 20 are already checked by '2' and '3')
check 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56,... (again, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42 are redundant checked)
```

the evaluation steps after the enhancement:

```
check 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14,...
check 9, 12, 15, 18, 21,...
check 25, 30, 35, ...
check 49, 56, ...
```